# Look for specific sequence of characters in a file and store a sequence of characters/numbers after it in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filereader

I am trying to open up a .htm file and read a revision number of a file from it.

Let's say these are the lines in the file.

```
I don't want to read this.
I don't want to read this. 
I don't want to read this. I don't want to read this. I don't want to read this. I don't want to read this. 
Now, I want to look for the following characters "HIJK @ " and read the number following it. Say 123456.
It will be in a line like this HIJK @ 123456
```

I want to look for the specific sequence of characters "HIJK @ " and read the number following it and store that number in a variable. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: And so far you tried what?

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach :

1. Parse the file using a parser (because it is a htm file) Line-by-Line (maybe use JSoup)
2. On each line (read as a string), use `contains("HIJK @")`.
3. If 2 is true, do `replaceAll(".*HIJK @(//d+).*","$1")`;
4. Bingo!, you got your number
5. Happy coding.